# spilt a string into key value pairs with a deliminator using scala

Tags: scala

I want to split the containing key value pairs to a deliminator `|`

`a=bc=df=d` into

```
a=b|c=d|f=d
```

Comment: And what if you get something like `a=bcd=ef`? Where should that place its delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

If your keys values are one character as in your example,

```
scala> "a=bc=df=d".grouped(3).toList.mkString("|")
res1: String = a=b|c=d|f=d
```

*does not work if your key value are strings. (eg. below)*

```
a=appleb=bananac=cat
```

Comment: string is very long in size

Comment: how do you know where to split then?? say `kjsfjks=sbjksgjsgfjhsfg=jsfjsgjfhgs=sajkfhjksfhj`